# Add space between zurb columns

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have simple structure based on zurb foundation 5.

I have a left bar which will show menu items and right bar which will have actual page contents.

I am trying to add `margin-right:20px;` to class `white-bar`. this breaks the design. I want to add space between two so that background image will be visible.

I also want to me in middle of the page vertically.

Fiddle Example http://jsfiddle.net/PZuLm/1/

```
<div class="row wrapper">
    <!--left bar-->
    <div class="small-12 medium-3 large-3 columns white-bar"></div>
    <!--left bar-->
    <!--Content area-->
    <div class="small-12 medium-9 large-9 columns content-bar"></div>
    <!--Content area-->
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
solution

I used `background-clip: content-box;` but i am not sure if this supported by all or old browsers.

```
.white-bar
{
    background-color:#fff;
    height:700px;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Last version of Foundation requires IE 9+ anyway so support of `background-clip` in older browsers is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/pvG7V/

**html**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-2 columns"></div>
    <div class="medium-2 columns"></div>
    <div class="medium-2 columns"></div>
    <div class="medium-2 columns"></div>
    <div class="medium-2 columns"></div>
    <div class="medium-2 columns"></div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
body{
    background-color:pink;
}
.columns{
    height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em){
    .columns + .columns{
        padding:0;
        padding-left:20px;
        background-clip: content-box;
    }
}
```

**Another way (without `background-clip`):**

http://jsfiddle.net/63SE4/

```
body{
    background-color:pink;
}
.columns{
    height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em){
    .columns + .columns:before{
        content: "";
        display:block;
        width:20px;
        height:100%;
        background-color:pink;
    }
}
```